# FX9500 LLRP User Application Connection Issue

Tags: java, rfid, jamvm, llrp

I'm working with a Motorola (Zebra) `FX9500` RFID reader and trying to get a user application running that integrates with the LLRP Toolkit.  The `FX9500` comes preloaded with JamVM that supports java 1.5.  My test application is simple: connects to the reader, deletes any `RO_SPECs`, then disconnects.  When I run the application from my dev machine I'm able to execute with no issue.  When I upload and run the program as a User Application on the FX9500 I get the message below when trying to connect to the LLRP server on the reader:

```
org.llrp.ltk.net.LLRPConnectionAttemptFailedException: Connection request timed out after 10000 ms.
    at org.llrp.ltk.net.LLRPConnection.checkLLRPConnectionAttemptStatus(LLRPConnection.java:69)
    at org.llrp.ltk.net.LLRPConnector.connect(LLRPConnector.java:149)
    at LLRPReader.connect(LLRPReader.java:15)
    at LLRPMain.main(LLRPMain.java:26)
```

I get this message after about 4 seconds - not the full 10 seconds timeout specified.  Below is my connect method:

```
public void connect(String ipAddress) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Connecting to reader " + ipAddress);
        reader = new LLRPConnector(this, ipAddress);
        ((LLRPConnector) reader).connect(TIMEOUT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Unsure if this is code related (my code or LLRP Toolkit), or something specific to `JamVM/FX9500`.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, If you found solution please share it will be helpful for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Balaji A solution was never found for this.  Zebra suggested I use an FX7500 instead of the FX9500 as user applications are fully supported on that platform.